# Python MongoDB json_util Overflow Error

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7

I'm trying to extract MongoDB Document with Json_util module. 
The Document contain: 
Date attribute with un valid date values like Date(-12394774152040).

I cannot extract this document since Json_Util throw Overflow Error
out of range since it's trying to extract this value into datatime python range.

Is there an option to extract it as string?

Comment: Cannot repoduce this. My attempt produces `"date": {"$date": -12394774152040}` just like it should. How are you using this? Should be something like `import bson from bson.json_util import dumps for doc in coll.find(): dumps(doc)` ( with linebreaks and indents of course ) basically speaking. It's also most certainly not out of range for `datetime` either, though I'm not sure why you have such a precision date stored for a time in year 1577.

Comment: It contains rubbish date that cam from client data.
I still don't understand how can load this date as string
and avoid error?